# Not displaying the last value for ksort in php

Tags: php, sorting

I have this sorting algorithm to sort the `$days` in reference to `$daysOfWeek` but I'm not sure why the last value is not being include to my array. Here is the code below

```
#default array
$daysOfWeek = array('M','T','W','TH','F');
#your array
$days = array('T','W','TH','','');
#create a new array with key association property
$daysAux = array();
foreach($days as $k=>$v) {
    $key = array_search($v, $daysOfWeek);
    if($key !== FALSE) {
        $daysAux[$key] = $v;
    }
    else
        $daysAux[$key] = '';
    }
# array before sort
echo '<pre/>';print_r($daysAux);
ksort($daysAux);
$days = $daysAux;
#final result
echo '<pre/>';print_r($days);


#output
Array
(
 [1] => T
 [2] => W
 [3] => TH
 [0] => 
)
Array
(
 [0] => 
 [1] => T
 [2] => W
 [3] => TH
)

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
Array
(
[0] =>
[1] => T
[2] => W
[3] => TH
[4] => 
)
```

Comment: whats your expected output

Comment: i have edit the question

Comment: why do you expect that?

Comment: I have to sort it so that if there is no specific day in that array it will only push a blank string. Example. if 'M' is not in the array it will only push a blank in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code code should say `$daysAux[$k] =` instead of `$daysAux[$key] =`

beacuse otherwise when `$key` is `false` it will just overwrite the same entry instead of creating a new one

also need to swap `days` and `daysOfWeek` in the loop.

```
#default array
$daysOfWeek = array('M','T','W','TH','F');
#your array
$days = array('T','W','TH','','');
#create a new array with key association property
$daysAux = array();
foreach($days as $k=>$v) {
    $key = array_search($v, $daysOfWeek);
    if($key !== FALSE) {
        $daysAux[$key] = $v;
    }
    else
        $daysAux[$key] = '';
    }
# array before sort
echo '<pre/>';print_r($daysAux);
ksort($daysAux);
$days = $daysAux;
#final result
echo '<pre/>';print_r($days);
```

Comment: this is the output I have when I use `$v` `Array([] => [T] => T [TH] => TH [W] => )`

Comment: ah, yeah two bugs for the price of one! edited and tested.

Comment: i got it now thank you! I've been stuck in this code for awhile now.